# Laravel Foreach Looping

Tags: laravel, foreach, iteration, laravel-5.6

I need to display the previous value of the iterated array, here is code

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Customer ID</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
    <th>Delivery Address</th>
    <th>Contact No.</th>
    <th>Zip Code</th>
    <th>Payment Terms</th>
    <th>Credit Limit</th>
</tr>
<?php $previousValue = null; ?>
@foreach($customer_count as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$previousValue=$value->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->delivery_address }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->contact_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->area_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->payment_term_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->credit_limit }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I need to display the previous name of Customer in the iteration?
Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set value at the end , I set blank for first

```
 @foreach($customer_count as $key => $value)
      <tr>
           <td>{{$previousValue or ""}}</td>
           .....
           .....
      </tr>
      <?php $previousValue = $value->customer_name ?>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: This work thanks mate!!! specially the "or" part is so helpful !!! cheers

Answer (score 0):

$customer_count[$key - 1]

Of course you'll need to check if that exists or use the null-coalesce operator or something, so:

```
@php

$previous = $customer_count[$key - 1] ?? false;

@endphp
```

Then use:

```
@if( $previous ) 
... some stuff ...
@endif
```

wherever you need to inject.

Comment: already tried this one but 
Undefined offset: -1 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fdis-laravel\resources\views\report\customer-count-group-detail.blade.php)

Comment: Yes, that why I said use the null-coalesce operator. Look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<td>{{ (!$loop->first) ? $customer_count[$key - 1]->customer_name : '' }}</td>
```

You can read more about foreach loop [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade).

Answer (score 0):

At very first set the previous value as blank and then at the bottom set value in `$previousValue`

```
<?php $previousValue = '';?>
@foreach($customer_count as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $previousValue }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->customer_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->delivery_address }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->contact_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->area_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->payment_term_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->credit_limit }}</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $previousValue = $value->customer_name; ?>
@endforeach
```